# ASP.NET Session bool variable is set to null in page load

Tags: asp.net, session, boolean

I am receiving this error message when I debug my program.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

That error happens on this line:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
bool x = (bool)Session["IsConnectionInfoSet"];--> error here
if (IsPostBack && x)
//do something with the bool x variable
}
```

Postback is invoked by:

```
protected void btnDo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//do something
Session["IsConnectionInfoSet"] = true;
//do something
}
```

This error happened in Visual Studio 2008, .NET Framework 3.5.

Can someone give me advice on how this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Page_Load method is always run before any event handlers.  As a result, the page_load will run, find null and throw an error, all before you click handler has a chance to set this session value.

Here's a safer way to access this session value

```
bool x = Session["IsConnectionInfoSet"] == null ? false :
          (bool)Session["IsConnectionInfoSet"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //this is the first time page load.
    }
    else
    {
        if (Session["IsConnectionInfoSet"] != null)
        {
            bool x = (bool)Session["IsConnectionInfoSet"];

            if (x)
            {
                //do something with the bool x variable
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps